# QNAP Nas and Printer driver

Tags: linux, printing, nas, network-printer, qnap

I have a QNAP NAS TS-239 Pro II and a Kyocera FS-820 USB printer.

When adding the printer to the NAS, it is recognized well and I can immediately see it in my List of Printers on Ubuntu Client.

But when printing, only the control characters get printed on an endless amount of pages.

I found a similar issue posted [here](https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=87214), but the thread doesn't provide any answer.

When connecting the printer locally to my Ubuntu computer and try to print directly with default settings I have the same issue. It works after changing the ppd manually to FS-920 Foomatic/ljet4 [en].

I thought the Server should take care of the correct driver, so that any computer can just print. How can I change the driver used by the NAS ? The NAS GUI doesn't allow to change drivers.

I have access via SSH, but lpstat gives me following output:

```
# lpstat -a
lpstat: No destinations added
```

Device URI is `ipp://NASBF5A68.local:631/printers/NASBF5A68PR5`